# Umbraco ContentService not updating checboxlist in document cache

Tags: database, caching, content-management-system, umbraco

I'm creating about 500 pages in a new Umbraco v6.1.6 website using an import script I've coded. I'm using the ContentService api to create the new pages. They are created and seem to save fine. However if I request the value of a checbox list from one of the new pages, I get an empty string.

I've verified that the property is empty in the umbraco.config file however If I manually save the page from the Umbraco back office. the cache will update with the correct value and I suddenly get the correct value returned.

Is there a way to force a cache update or some other form of fix for this issue?

This is the CreateContent method I'm using:

```
public static IContent CreateContent(string name, string documentTypeAlias, int parentId, Dictionary properties, bool publish = false, int author = 0)
{
    IContent document = null;

    ContentService contentService = new ContentService();
    document = contentService.CreateContent(
                    name, // the name of the document
                    parentId, // the parent id should be the id of the group node 
                    documentTypeAlias, // the alias of the Document Type
                    author);

    foreach (string property in properties.Keys)
    {
        document.SetValue(property, properties[property]);
    }

    // If publish is true, then save and publish the document
    if (publish)
    {
        contentService.SaveAndPublish(document);
    }
    // Else, just save it
    else
    {
        contentService.Save(document);
    }

    return document;
}
```

Edit:

After looking into the database, I can see that cmsContentXml has the property but the data within it is the same as umbraco.config. I looked into cmsPropertyData and the data is present. So I guess the question is how do I get the data from cmsPropertyData to cmsContentXml?

My Question is simelar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722347/umbraco-6-1-1-when-i-publish-content-via-the-content-service-tags-type-property however it has no replies.

Comment: How is the value (for your checkbox list) formatted in your properties Dictionary? If you import a value, which doesn't show up in the XML cache, but does if you save from the backoffice it sounds like your checkbox property is not properly saved during your import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data from `cmsContentXml` gets dumped directly into the `umbraco.config` file so thankfully these are the same.

To make your code a bit more DRY (you're always saving the document in both the if and the else, try this and update the `SaveAndPublish` method to `Publish` (and in v7 you can use `PublishWithResult` to get a detailed result of the publish action):

```
contentService.Save(document);

// If publish is true, then save and publish the document
if (publish)
{
    contentService.Publish(document);
}
```

In v7 you could then have a look at the publishResult. If there's something wrong then this will tell you what it is. Most likely it'll just work fine this way though (which could mean that SaveAndPublish is broken, but let's figure out if publishResult has errors).

Comment: 'contentService' does not contain a definition for PublishWithResult. Any ideas?

Comment: I replaced the line 'var publishresult = ...' in your answer with 'contentService.Publish(document);' and suddenly it worked. Which is a mystery because both Publish and SaveAndPublish use the same method 'SaveAndPublishDo' however I can't say I've done much with the Umbraco source code.

Comment: Ah sorry, PublishWithResult is new in v7 not in v6 yet.

Comment: Updated the answer, I'll figure out what's wrong with PublishWithResult and see if we can fix that.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully moving to v7 soon. Probably wait for at least one more release.